# Flutter panic button on mobile phones

Tags: flutter

`I trying to create an app that uses power button as panic button. It has to be clicked 3 times to trigger a method that makes a call. The problem is I cant find flutter packages that I can use to count and return number of times the button was pressed.

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:android_physical_buttons/android_physical_buttons.dart';
import 'package:flutter_phone_direct_caller/flutter_phone_direct_caller.dart';

    void main() {
       runApp(const App());
    }

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  State<App> createState() => _State();
     }

class _State extends State<App> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    AndroidPhysicalButtons.listen((key) {
      print(key); //Key.power, Key.volume
      _callNumber;
    });
      }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(
       appBar: AppBar( 
           title: const Text('Android Physical      Buttons'))));
    }

  _callNumber() async{
  const number = '002665365878899'; //set the number here
  bool? res = await FlutterPhoneDirectCaller.callNumber(number);
     }
     }
```

I used android_physical_buttons: ^0.1.0 to detect changes on physical buttons and flutter_phone_direct_caller: ^2.1.1 to make a call. I want to be able to count number of times a button was pressed and return a value.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a state variable to store the count?

```
AndroidPhysicalButtons.listen((key) {
  print(key); //Key.power, Key.volume
  if (key == Key.power) _powerKeyPressCount++;
  else _powerKeyPressCount=0;
  if (_powerKeyPressCount==3){
    _powerKeyPressCount=0;
    _callNumber();
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes but it doesn't work because it resets _powerKeyPressCount when I press the power button for the first time so it never gets to 3. If only I could keep the counting variable when the power button is pressed

Comment: Use shared preferences